# How to use config properties file throughout the classes?

Tags: java, properties

I need my Java app to read the config properties from a file and use them throughout the classes. I'm thinking of a separate class, that would return a map of `property_key:property_value` for each of the properties in the file. Then I would read the values from this map in other classes.
Maybe there are other, more commonly used options?

My properties file is simple and has about 15 entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `java.util.Properties` to load it. It implements `Map` already. 
You can load and get hold of the properties statically. Here's an example assuming that you've a `config.properties` file in the `com.example` package:

```
public final class Config {

    private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            properties.load(loader.getResourceAsStream("com/example/config.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getSetting(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Which can be used as

```
String foo = Config.getSetting("foo");
// ...
```

You could if necessary abstract this implementation away by an interface and get the instance by an abstract factory.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not actually work. I'm always getting the ExceptionInInitializerError. The simplest case I'm trying to test with is calling System.out.println(ConfigReader.getSetting("property.name")); from the main method of another class. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the root cause of this error? When getting exceptions, you should always look down in the stacktrace for the bottommost "caused by" or "root cause" part for the *real* cause of the problem. Anyway, I'll guess that the `config.properties` is actually not in the root of the classpath (as in the given example) or that you forgot to fix/substitute the example path with the actual path (for the case that it has a different filename or is in a package).

Comment: The root cause is the Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException. The properties file is inside the package, on one level with the ConfigReader and Main class. I also tried the absolute path to the properties file, which does not work either.

Comment: You should then use `getResourceAsStream("com/example/config.properties")`. I updated the answer to include the example. By the way, I'm not sure what you mean with "absolute path", but please do not ever think about using local disk file system paths like `C:\path\to\config.properties` for this. Always grab them from the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, that works and now i understand the process. What would be the solution if I need the properties file to reside somewhere on the file system outside the package or outside the classpath?

Comment: Just add that path to the classpath of your runtime environment. This way you keep the application free from environment specific clutter which would make it unportable. It you *really* need to, you could also specify the path as a VM argument or at highest an environment variable. It'll be available by `System#getProperty()` or `System#getenv()` respectively.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4074/discussion-between-andriy-yurchuk-and-balusc)

Comment: @BalusC Great usage of static method. Loved your answer